# Incompatible libpng version

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, caffe, libpng

I compiled Caffe and run command line classifier. Before compiling, I checked libpng version with `libpng-config --ldflags --cflags` and got:

```
-L/work/zhang/common/tools/anaconda2/lib -lpng16
-I/work/zhang/common/tools/anaconda2/include/libpng16
```

Both version 1.6

However, when I run the binary:

```
**libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.6.13**
**libpng warning: Application is running with png.c from libpng-1.2.49**
**libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library**
F0519 22:17:15.609571 13943 classification.cpp:251] Check failed: !img.empty() Unable to decode image ../web-cnn/test_labeled_images/AND18.png
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@ 0x7f181d546b9d google::LogMessage::Fail()
@ 0x7f181d54abb7 google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
@ 0x7f181d548a39 google::LogMessage::Flush()
@ 0x7f181d548d3d google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
@ 0x407254 main
@ 0x380ae1ed5d (unknown)
@ 0x4041c9 (unknown)
```

Then I run `ldd <binary> | grep libpng`, got:

```
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 (0x0000003810200000)
libpng16.so.16 => /work/zhang/common/usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f9396e2b000)
```

How can I force it using same version of libpng?

Comment: Why don't you remove `libpng-1.2.49` then?

Comment: @Raptor I am not admin of the server. Can't remove packages or create symbolic link of libraries

Comment: Not the admin of the server, but you can compile and install Caffe?

Comment: @Raptor Yes, in my own directory